# Hover on image to add overlay in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have more than one image in a div wrapper. I want to add overlay on image when user hover over the image. I am trying to do using code shown below.

```js
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length; i++) {
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    
    let elementExists = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
    let Center = document.createElement('div');
    let Text = document.createElement('div');
     
    if (!elementExists) {
      let Wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      let parentElement = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
      Wrapper.classList.add('Wrapper');
      Wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
      
     Center.classList.add('Center');
     Text.innerHTML = "Sample text";
      
     parentElement.appendChild(Wrapper);
     Wrapper.appendChild(Center);
     Center.appendChild(Text);
    
      Wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
        if (document.getElementById('wrapper')) {
            document.getElementById('wrapper').remove();
        }
      });
    }
});
}
```

```css
.col-md-6 {
        width: 375px;
        height: 211px;
        margin: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
        .Wrapper {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1000;
        font-family: arial;
        color: #fff;
        top: 0;
    }

    .Center {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" />
</a>
</div>
```

Every time I hover on first image, code just works fine. But when I hover on 2nd image it adds overlay on 1st image only.(It should add overlay on second image) I tried to debug the code and `let parentElement = event.currentTarget.parentElement;` is showing the a href only.

**NOTE:** I came to know its because I am giving position: absolute to Wrapper. I only want to make changes in JavaScript file and at max to css.
Please let me know if you found error in the code.

Comment: it looks like your absolute positioning in CSS is the cause, the Wrapper stays exactly where you have placed it. Btw, a  quick way to optimize your current for loop would be to extract the `document.getElementsByTagName` outside of the loop and keep it as a local variable, no need to query them on every iteration of the loop and inside the loop again

Comment: @Icepickle This is just a sample code that I have made. I am iterating images in much different way in actual code. Thank!
Can you please tell me fix, how can I change CSS to fix it?

Comment: You can do it with simple CSS as well
https://codepen.io/ArnaudBalland/pen/vGZKLr

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a css problem. Just add this to what you currently have:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
}

.Center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also I removed the final `Text` div and added its text to the `Center` div, as it triggered the mouseout event and made it flicker.

```js
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length; i++) {
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    
    let elementExists = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
    let Center = document.createElement('div');
     
    if (!elementExists) {
      let Wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      let parentElement = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
      Wrapper.classList.add('Wrapper');
      Wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
      
     Center.classList.add('Center');
     Center.innerHTML = "Sample text";
      
     parentElement.appendChild(Wrapper);
     Wrapper.appendChild(Center);
    
      Wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
        if (document.getElementById('wrapper')) {
            document.getElementById('wrapper').remove();
        }
      });
    }
});
}
```

```css
.col-md-6 {
  width: 375px;
  height: 211px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.Wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.Center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" />
</a>
</div>
```